# Setting container width on material-ui for React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have recently started with `React.js` along with `material-ui` library. I am aware of the `Grid` system for layouts that `material-ui` uses. However, unlike `Bootstrap`, the `container` extends from end to end. Say, I want to create a global container to hold content which should have a max width of `1140px`, what is the correct way to do it? Currently I am using `withStyles` provided by `material-ui` as shown by the code sample below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = {
  contentBody: {
    maxWidth: '1140px',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto'
  }
};

class ContentBody extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid container className={this.props.classes.contentBody}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(ContentBody);
```